# Compute angle between two points in a sphere.

Tags: spherical-geometry, spheres, angle

Exist an equation that provide the angle between two points in a sphere.

What I'm looking is not easy to explain, anyway assume to have two points in a sphere than connect this tho points with a line (A and B in the figure) and than how can I compute the angle between the line and a fix reference line or a kind of orientation of reference (as if the two points were in a normal plane)? Is there any way to do something like that?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to compute the angle at $B$, formed between the great circle containing $A$ and $B$, and the great circle containing $C$ and $B$ (In other words: in your picture, is the black dot near the top the center of the sphere?) ? If so, it's fairly easy. Do you have $xyz$ coordinates for $A, B$, and $C$, or latitude-longitude, or something else?

Comment: @JohnHughes I would like to have an equation that compute the angle between a fix great circle (i.e. the Greenwich Meridian that I assume passing through B) and the he great circle containing A. I have azimuth and elevation for both A and B.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to give two answers. The first I'll derive, but it uses some linear algebra, which may not be familiar to you, and converts to "xyz" coordinates to do its work. The second uses just angles, and I'll just give you the formula and a references. Ideas needed:

1. I'll represent an arrow from the origin $(0,0,0)$ to a point $(a, b, c)$ by writing $[a, b, c]$, and call it a "vector". I call this "the vector corresponding to the point $(a,b,c)$", just to have a name for it.
2. "cross product of vectors": $[x, y, z] \times [a,b, c] = [yc - zb, za - xc, xb-ya]$. If the two vectors are nonzero and not parallel, then the cross product is a vector perpendicular to both.
3. "dot product of vectors": $[x, y, z] \cdot [a, b, c] = ax + yb + zc$.
4. "length of a vector $v = [x, y, z]$: we define $\| v \| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 = z^2} = \sqrt{ v \cdot v }.$
5. If $v$ and $w$ are nonzero vectors, then the angle $\theta$ between then satisfies $ \cos \theta = \frac{v \cdot w} {\|v \| ~ \|w\|}$.
6. There's a function, $atan2$, in most software packages, that takes a non-origin point point $(x, y)$ of the plane and produces $atan2(x, y)$, which is the angle, measured counterclockwise from the positive $x$-axis, to the ray from $(0,0)$ through $(x, y)$. (It's a lot like "arctan", but gives correct answers for points in the 3rd and fourth quadrant by checking the sign of $x$.)
7. A vector $[x, y, z]$ represents a point with spherical coordinates, where the "latitude coordinate" $\theta$ is $atan2(x, y)$, and the "longitude coordinate" is $\phi = \cos^{-1} z$. This assumes that the coordinates are set up so that the $xy$ plane is the equatorial plane, and the two "poles" lie at $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,0, -1)$, and that we are measuring in units that make the radius of the sphere "1". Note that the $\phi$ coordinate of a point on the equator is 0, with the phi coordinate being $\pi/2$ (or 90 degrees) a the north pole. If you are used to measuring from $0$ (at the north pole) to $\pi$ (or 180 degrees) at the south pole, you'll need a conversion.
8. The inverse transformation, from $(\phi, \theta)$ coordinates to $xyz$ is $(x, y, z) = (\cos \theta \sin \phi, \sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \phi)$.
9. Points $(x,y,z)$ on the plane $Ax + By + Cz = 0$ (which intersects the unit sphere in a great-circle, because the plane passes through the origin, which is the center of the sphere) can also be described by saying that each point $(x, y, z)$ corresponds to a vector $v = [x, y, z]$ with the property that $n \cdot v = 0$, where $n$ is the vector $[A, B, C]$. We call $n$ "a normal vector for the plane."

I think that's it. :)

Now let's look at your diagram. I'm going to call the center of the sphere $U = (0,0,0)$, just to have a name for it.

The great circle containing $B$ and $C$ lies in a plane that's perpendicular to the vectors $b$ and $c$ for $B$ and $C$. One such vector is $n_1 = b \times c$. The same goes for the great circle through $A$ and $B$. If we say that $a$ is the vector corresponding to $A$, then one normal to the plane of that second great circle is $n_2 = a \times b$.

The cool observation here is that the angle $\theta$ that you're looking for at $B$ is exactly the angle between these two planes...which is also exactly the angle between their normal vectors! And from item 5 above, you can compute this by 
$$
\theta = \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{n_1\cdot n_2}{\|n_1\|~ \|n_2 \|}\right).
$$

So your complete "formula" for computing the angle is this:

1. Convert each point, $A$, $B$, $C$ in polar coordinates, to rectangular, using item 8, to get coordinate triples that we treat as vectors $a$, $b$, $c$.
2. Compute $n_1 = b \times c$, $n_2 = a \times b$, using item 2.
3. Compute $\| n_1 \| $ and $\| n_2 \|$ using item 4, and $n_1 \cdot n_2$ using item 3.
4. Compute $\theta = \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{n_1\cdot n_2}{\|n_1\|~ \|n_2 \|}\right)$.

That wasn't so bad, was it? :)

In general, the formula for the cosine of the angle at $B$ is

$$
\cos B = \frac{\cos b - \cos a \cos c}{\sin a \sin c}
$$
where in this case, I'm using "B" to denote the angle you've drawn at point $B$, but "$b$" to indicate the angle subtended by the points $A$ and $C$ from the origin $U$, and similarly for $a$ and $c$. (You've used these lower-case letters to label three arcs, and I'm just saying that they denote not the length of the arc in miles, but rather the measure of the arc (a number between $0$ and $180$ degrees, or between $0$ and $\pi$ radians).

Computing those subtended angles? I'd be inclined to use rectangular coordinates and dot products as I did before. :)

Also: the angle at "B" is ambiguous: if you pick the angle $\pi + B$, you'll still eventually get to point $A$. If you're writing a program, you may find that the inverse cosine messes you up sometimes because of this.

Most books on celestial navigation derive these formulas, as will any book on spherical trigonometry.

Comment: Your answer it's really amazing. I really appreciate your effort. I have two clarifications. 1) regarding the computation of $\theta$ is it a $cos^{-1}$ right? Instead of $cos^{1}$. Then, 2) assuming I have two point $A$ and $B$, and I want to find the angle between them. Can I always use as referring point $C$ let's say the point with $C = (0,0)$ as azimut and elevation?

Comment: (1) Yes, it should be "inverse cos"; I've edited to fix that-- thanks! (2) "the angle between two points" isn't really well-defined --- you need a point of reference. For points on the sphere, we almost always take the center of the sphere $U$, and then the angle from $A$ to $B$ comes from the following: convert both to rectangular coords $a$ and $b$ using item 8; the subtended angle is then $\cos^{-1} (a \cdot b)$. (The lengths of $a$ and $b$ are both $1$, so we can leave those out!)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation!

Comment: I think there's a sign error in this answer? Any two planes have two complementary angles between them, and computing normal vectors cyclically ($a\times b$, $b\times c$, $c\times a$) I believe gives the complements of the angles found in a triangle. Taking the complement of the final $\theta$, or swapping the order of the cross product for one of $n_1,n_2$, should work?

Answer (score 0):

An equation that provides the angle between two points in a sphere:

Let the angle between two points A and B be $ω$, then

$$cos(ω)=cos(θ_1-θ_2)*cos(φ_1-φ_2)$$

where, $A=[L_1,θ_1,φ_1]=(x_1,y_1,h_1)$, $B=[L_2,θ_2,φ_2]=(x_2,y_2,h_2)$.

$L=\sqrt{r^2+h^2}$ , $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} , θ=tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}),  φ=tan^{-1}(\frac{h}{r})$.

Comment: Why is this getting down voted? I'm about to use the equations outlined here to solve my own problem . Is there something wrong with them? If this method works does it apply to higher dimensional spaces as well?