# Help with geometry of triangles in spheres.

Tags: geometry, triangles, 3d, spheres

I am trying to get my head around the geometry of triangles inscribed into spheres (not spherical triangles - the triangle itself is a plane).  I have been working with triangles in circles, and now I need to extrapolate this to 3D.  I'd like to learn this from basic principles, and so would appreciate a pointer at a primer or something similar, but I will include my exact problem below as well.

I have a triangle $\triangle ABC$, inscribed in a unit sphere, center $O$. $O$ is not on the plane $ABC$. Taking the circle around each side and with its center at $O$, bisect each side of the triangle and push that point out to a point on the surface of that circle. This gives us six chords of the sphere, $AX$, $XB$, $BY$, $YC$, $CZ$, $ZA$. I have done all the math to this point, using the circles $AB$, $BC$, and $CA$ around $O$, to get the lengths of the six new chords, and the angles at $O$ for each one. But now I want to figure out three NEW circles, $XY$, $YZ$ and $ZX$, around the same center point $O$, so I can work out those lengths and angles.  These would still be unit circles, as the points are on the surface of the unit sphere I started with. The angle $\angle XOY$ would be the angle between the planes $ABO$ and $BCO$, if I'm not mistaken, but not sure how to get that angle, and not completely sure that that assumption is correct in the first place. (those planes intersect on the line $BO$, so is that angle just the same as $\angle ABC$? This seems too simple, but if I'm right, this makes my day much easier!)

This is only the first step in my project, so I really want to learn this stuff, not just get answers.
Any help getting my brain to pop out of 2D into 3D is appreciated, either to get directly to the answer here, or pointers to a good source to start learning (in which case I will come back and answer this myself).

Comment: If O is not in the plane of ABC than the circle in which it is inscribed is not a unit circle. What you mean by the term push? From O or on the perpendicular to the midpoints?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1715844/1257.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @brainjam no, I don't think so.  I'm looking for an angle at the center of the sphere.  I'm looking to describe the chords between the new points, not the angles between them at the surface.

Comment: @Moti I didn't say that Triangle ABC was inscribed in a unit circle, I said it was in the unit sphere (with all three points on the surface).  The circumcircle of ABC is definitely NOT a unit circle.  The circles I reference are unit circles around O (so on the surface of the sphere), through pairs of vertices on the triangle.

Push out to the surface of the sphere from the center, so from O. (which is a perpendicular line to the midpoints, but not the perpendcular line on the plane of the triangle)

Comment: But that answer explains that $\cos(\angle{XOY})=OX\cdot OY$(the "dot product of vectors"in 3.), which is what I think you want. (to get the actual angle use $\cos^{-1}(OX\cdot OY)$).

Comment: I don't see anything in that answer that is relevant to this question.

Also, I don't understand "OX.OY(the dot product of vectors)" - I am working (up to this point) in 2D circles and triangles.  All the information I have thus far are angles and lengths.  The initial triangle could be any arbitrary triangle, and I am working with this circumscribed sphere in order to generate these new points.  I am making the assumption that this sphere is the unit sphere because it's ratios I'm interested in, ultimately, so I can plug in any 3 lengths for the original triangle and get these new lengths.

Comment: I have read, re-read and re-re-read that answer over and over, I can't see anything that describes an angle at the origin, nor anything that even looks like the formula you suggested here, even if I did understand it.  the closest thing to it (the only thing using an inverse cos) is θ=cos−1(n1⋅n2/(∥n1∥*∥n2∥)). - this is not the same as what you've said here, and doesn't describe an angle at the origin, so I'm not sure that this is what you're pointing me at.

Comment: $OX$ and $OY$ are the vectors from the center $O$ of the sphere to the points $X,Y$.  The dot in $OX\cdot OY$ is the dot product defined in point 3 of the answer.  This dot product is the cosine of the angle you are seeking.

Comment: How do I generate vectors to arbitrary points on the surface of the sphere?

I started with lengths AB, BC, and CA, was able to calculate the angles at the center, bisect those angles and generate the new chord lengths.  How do I get from any of this information to vectors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113891/discussion-between-brainjam-and-ryno).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @brainjam, who has helped me plug through all the steps to get to my answer.  Here it is step by step.

Given the distances $AB,BC,CA$ I need the co-ordinates of the points $A,B,C$ in 3D space to make this work.  Because the triangle is arbitrary in its alignment on the sphere, I can rotate the sphere at will.  So I placed point $B$ at $(1,0,0)$, and $A$ on the $xz$ plane.

The angle $\angle BOA$ = $\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{2-AB^2}{2}\right)$.

Then point $A = (\cos(\angle BOA),0,\sin(\angle BOA))$.

Point $C=(x,y,z)$ can be solved using the distances from points $A,B$ and $OC=1$.

$OC = 1 = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$
which gives $1 = x^2+y^2+z^2$.

For x:
$$
\begin{align}
BC &= \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2+z^2} \\
BC^2 &= (x-1)^2+y^2+z^2 \\
BC^2 &= x^2 - 2x + 1 + y^2 + z^2 \\
BC^2 &= -2x + 2  \\
-2x &= BC^2-2   \\
x &=1-BC^2/2  \\
\end{align}
$$

For y:
$$
\begin{align}
AC &= \sqrt{(x-A_x)^2+y^2+(z-A_z)^2}\\
AC^2 &= (x-A_x)^2+y^2+(z-A_z)^2\\
y^2 &= AC^2-(x-A_x)^2-(z-A_z)^2\\
y &=\sqrt{AC^2-(x-A_x)^2-(z-A_z)^2}\\
\end{align}
$$

For z, substituting $y^2$ into $BC^2 = (x-1)^2+y^2+z^2$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
BC^2 &= (x-1)^2+z^2 + AC^2-(x-A_x)^2-(z-A_z)^2 \\
(z-A_z)^2-z^2 &= AC^2-BC^2+(x-1)^2-(x-A_x)^2 \\
A_z^2-2zA_z &= AC^2-BC^2+(x-1)^2-(x-A_x)^2 \\
-2zA_z &= AC^2-BC^2+(x-1)^2-(x-A_x)^2-A_z^2 \\
z &= \frac{AC^2-BC^2+(x-1)^2-(x-A_x)^2-A_z^2}{-2A_z} \\
\end{align}
$$

Those three provide $C=(x,y,z)$ in terms of the initial lengths of the sides.

Now that I have the point coordinates of all three points, I can calculate the midpoints $M_{AB},M_{BC},M_{CA}$on each side.

Calculating the angle between each pair of midpoints using the dot product:
$$\angle{M_{AB}OM_{BC}} = \cos^{-1}(M_{AB}\cdot M_{BC}/|M_{AB}||M_{BC}|)$$

and then the chord length between the points projected out along lines $OM_{AB}$ and $OM_{BC}$ to the surface of the sphere, is given by
$$\frac{\sin(M_{AB}OM_{BC})}{\sin(0.5(180-M_{AB}OM_{BC}))}.$$